# Python | Create combination of dictionary based on conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, combinations

I'm trying to create combination of dictionary based on some condition

below is the main dictionary:

```
payload = {
    "type": ["sedan","suv"],
    "name": ["car1","car2"],
    "color": ["black","white","green"],
    "version": ["mid","top"],
    "model": ["2","5","13"],
}
```

below are the conditions:

```
color = {
    "car1": ["black","green"],
    "car2":["white"]
    }
model = {
    "mid":["5"],
    "top":["13","5"]
}
```

For payload["name"] = "car1" the colors can be only be "black" or "green" even if the payload["color"] has more than these color.

for payload["name"] = "car2", it can have only be "white" color.

Same goes for model also, for mid version it can only have model as "5" and for top version it can have only "13" and "5".

below is the expected output:

```
[
{'type': 'sedan', 'name': 'car1', 'color': 'black', 'version': 'mid', 'model': '5'}, 
{'type': 'sedan', 'name': 'car1', 'color': 'black', 'version': 'top', 'model': '5'}, 
{'type': 'sedan', 'name': 'car1', 'color': 'black', 'version': 'top', 'model': '13'}, 
{'type': 'sedan', 'name': 'car1', 'color': 'green', 'version': 'mid', 'model': '5'}, 
{'type': 'sedan', 'name': 'car1', 'color': 'green', 'version': 'top', 'model': '5'}, 
{'type': 'sedan', 'name': 'car1', 'color': 'green', 'version': 'top', 'model': '13'}, 
{'type': 'suv', 'name': 'car1', 'color': 'black', 'version': 'top', 'model': '5'}, 
{'type': 'suv', 'name': 'car1', 'color': 'black', 'version': 'top', 'model': '13'}, 
{'type': 'suv', 'name': 'car1', 'color': 'black', 'version': 'mid', 'model': '5'}, 
{'type': 'suv', 'name': 'car1', 'color': 'green', 'version': 'top', 'model': '5'}, 
{'type': 'suv', 'name': 'car1', 'color': 'green', 'version': 'top', 'model': '13'},
{'type': 'suv', 'name': 'car1', 'color': 'green', 'version': 'mid', 'model': '5'},
{'type': 'sedan', 'name': 'car2', 'color': 'white', 'version': 'mid', 'model': '5'}, 
{'type': 'sedan', 'name': 'car2', 'color': 'white', 'version': 'top', 'model': '5'}, 
{'type': 'sedan', 'name': 'car2', 'color': 'white', 'version': 'top', 'model': '13'}, 
{'type': 'suv', 'name': 'car2', 'color': 'white', 'version': 'mid', 'model': '5'}, 
{'type': 'suv', 'name': 'car2', 'color': 'white', 'version': 'top', 'model': '5'}, 
{'type': 'suv', 'name': 'car2', 'color': 'white', 'version': 'top', 'model': '13'}  
]
```

Below is my code..it brings out all the combinations, how can i add the condition check to this. Can someone help?

```
import itertools
payload = {
    "type": ["sedan","suv"],
    "name": ["car1","car2"],
    "color": ["black","white","green"],
    "version": ["mid","top"],
    "model": ["2","5","13"],
}

color = {
    "car1": ["black","green"],
    "car2":["white"]
    }
model = {
    "mid":["5"],
    "top":["13","5"]
}
output = [dict(zip(payload.keys(), a)) for a in itertools.product(*payload.values())]
print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create a dataframe with the outputs and the filter it for each condition like below

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd
payload = {
    "type": ["sedan","suv"],
    "name": ["car1","car2"],
    "color": ["black","white","green"],
    "version": ["mid","top"],
    "model": ["2","5","13"],
}

color = {
    "car1": ["black","green"],
    "car2":["white"]
    }
model = {
    "mid":["5"],
    "top":["13","5"]
}
output = [dict(zip(payload.keys(), a)) for a in itertools.product(*payload.values())]
print(output)

df = pd.DataFrame(output)


# filter for car1 color
df = df.loc[~((df.name == 'car1') & ~(df.color.isin(color['car1']))),:] 

# filter for car2 color
df = df.loc[~((df.name == 'car2') & ~(df.color.isin(color['car2']))),:]

#filter for mid model
df = df.loc[~((df.version == 'mid') & ~(df.model.isin(model['mid']))),:]

#filter for topmodel
df = df.loc[~((df.version == 'top') & ~(df.model.isin(model['top']))),:]
df
```